# Getting latest command from function, but function exceeds "max-lisp-eval-depth"

Tags: functions, prefix-argument

This defines the Helm-source for `Emacs commands history`.

```
(defvar helm-source-emacs-commands-history
    (helm-build-sync-source "Emacs commands history"
    :candidates (lambda ()
                    (let ((cmds))
                    (dolist (elem extended-command-history)
                        (push (intern elem) cmds))
                    cmds))
    :coerce #'intern-soft
    :action #'command-execute)
    "Emacs commands history")
```

From this source you get the latest commands that you called with `M-x`. I would have a function, that calls the latest command that I called with `M-x` earlier. I read the [documentation about list elements](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Elements.html).

```
Function: car cons-cell
This function returns the value referred to by the first slot of the cons cell cons-cell. In other words, it returns the CAR of cons-cell.

As a special case, if cons-cell is nil, this function returns nil. Therefore, any list is a valid argument. An error is signaled if the argument is not a cons cell or nil.

(car '(a b c))
    ⇒ a
(car '())
    ⇒ nil
```

So I assume I need to replace the `push` with `car`, and return the result.

```
(dolist (elem extended-command-history)
(car (intern elem)))
```

But I got the error message

```
Debugger entered -- Lisp error (wrong-type-argument listp Info-next)
(Info-Next)
```

The `Info-Next` was indeed the latest command that I called with `M-x`.  However, I don't understand the error. Another way to get the latest called function.

```
(defun foobar ()
    (interactive)
    (call-interactively (intern (car extended-command-history))))
```

After calling `foobar`, I get the following error:

```
funcall-interactively: Lisp nesting exceeds `max-lisp-eval-depth'
```

Any suggestion to get the latest command?

Comment: I, for one, don't understand the question. But I sense that there is a question here and that others will understand it. I hope you find an answer.

Comment: Why aren't you using the default binding of `n` to call `Info-next` ?

Comment: In any case, you can't take the `car` of a symbol! `intern` returns a symbol.

Comment: @Drew I updated the bottom of my post. Maybe my question is more clear?

Comment: @phils so I need to replace the `intern`? If so, what do I need to apply then? Leaving out `intern` didn't help either.

Comment: I think you want `(defun foobar () (call-interactively (intern (car extended-command-history)))` but as things stand right now, the question is unclear. You're mixing your actual question with your personal research on the matter, and it ends up being difficult to understand.

Comment: ReneFroger: Showing what you've tried is certainly to be encouraged, but in this instance there's a lot of confusion. I suspect that YoungFrog's comment has interpreted and answered your question correctly. It's great that you've been using the documentation, so you should (re-)read the details of each of the functions for the working version of the code, and hopefully you'll be able to understand why that does what you wanted (and why your original code did not).

Comment: Take note that you can read all of the documentation inside of Emacs very conveniently. To start with, use `C-h f` to ask about any function (e.g. `intern`), and `C-h v` to ask about any variable (e.g. `extended-command-history`). All of the manuals are available through the Info reader (`C-h i`), including the Introduction to Emacs Lisp.

Comment: @YoungFrog, it didn't worked. After evaluating `(defun foobar ()
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively (intern (car extended-command-history))))`, I call `foobar`, and I get the error `funcall-interactively: Lisp nesting exceeds 'max-lisp-eval-depth'`.

Comment: @phils, you're right. The question is unclear, because I would like to tell why I would this function. But I have rewrote it. And your explaination about the documentation inside Emacs is wat I'm just reading, thanks for it. :-)

Comment: @ReneFroger Yes, well, don't call it with M-x. Or try this "improved" version `(defun foobar ()  (interactive)  (let ((history extended-command-history)        cmd)    (while (string= this-command (setq cmd (pop history))))    (message "Running cmd: %s" cmd)    (call-interactively (intern cmd))))`

Comment: Please don't post the same question here and on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31920069/729907). It's not forbidden, of course, but it just makes for more noise for everyone. (Just one opinion.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's explain the different code bits of your question (I'm reusing some of what I said in my comments).

What we find in the helm source definition is:

```
(let ((cmds))
  (dolist (elem extended-command-history)
    (push (intern elem) cmds))
  cmds)
```

This builds a list of symbols. Each element of `extended-command-history` is a string which is transformed into a symbol via `intern` and pushed to the list `cmds`. Once done, `cmds` is returned. Btw, another, more concise but not more efficient, way of doing this is

```
(nreverse (mapcar 'intern extended-command-history))
```

Now what you want is to run the first element of `extended-command-history` and run it as a command. So a first naive approach would be:

```
(defun foobar ()
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively (intern (car extended-command-history))))
```

But if you do `M-x foobar RET` this will end up running `foobar` (because `M-x` pushes `foobar` to `extended-command-history` before calling it), hence the error you mentionned :

> funcall-interactively: Lisp nesting exceeds `max-lisp-eval-depth'

To avoid this problem, one can run the first element of `extended-command-history` that is different from the current command. Here's some code to do this :

```
(defun foobar ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((history extended-command-history)
        cmd)
    ;; remove any occurence of this-command at the head of `history'.
    (while (string= this-command (setq cmd (pop history))))
    (message "Running cmd: %s" cmd)
    (call-interactively (intern cmd))))
```

As you mentionned, we could also run the `cadr` of `extended-command-history`, but it would be off by one in the case `foobar` is not ran via `M-x` but via some key binding (because in this case, it won't get added to the head of `extended-command-history`).

Comment: I'd like to add that I think you're solving your problem with the wrong tools. If you want to use a given command repeatedly, just bind it to a key (and maybe check that it is not bound already, using `C-h w` -- in the case of `Info-next` it is bound to `n`.)

Comment: YoungFrog, thanks for your helpful explaination. Now I understand better where I went wrong, and new ways to do it right, including checking if keys are bound. It's really appreciated, YoungFrog. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some asking and research, the error funcall-interactively: Lisp nesting exceeds max-lisp-eval-depth is quite reasonable. The last command will be foobar since it is interactive. Use use `cadr` instead of `car` in foobar.

Comment: Please note that this will fail if you decided to bind foobar to a key.

Comment: You're sharp and right. Indeed, I already noticed it after bounding it to a key. See my reply above on your solution.